# Access model and view information in grails controller integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing, render

Is there any way I can get what view and what has been passed as model after issuing render command in controller in integration test? Eg.:

```
render view: 'edit', model: [profileInstance: someProfile]
```

Any chance I can retrieve model and view to perform some assertions? I know how to do it in unit tests, but it would be handy in integration tests as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the render method from the Controller to be able to get the map that is passed to it in order to be able to get the model and the view. For this, you can declare a variable in the test method called renderMap and then change the render method to set it like this:

```
Map renderMap

registerMetaClass(MyController.class)
MyController.metaClass.render = {Map m ->
  renderMap = m
}
...
// Instantiate controller
// Call controller action
```

Then you can access some of the objects you set in the model like this:

```
def someObject = renderMap.model.someObject
```

And the view like this:

```
String view = renderMap.view
```

At some point you might want to restore your controller's metaClass as it was.

Comment: The method registerMetaClass exists in the GrailsUnitTestCase class, but since for integration tests I don't extend from this class what I did was moved that code to a base class for my integration tests, so you can check how the registerMetaClass method works in the source code of the GrailsUnitTestCase class and how the metaClass is restored in the tearDown method. If you still need me to put the exact code here, just let me know.

Comment: As clarification to Maricel's comment. The [GrailsUnitTestCase source code is here](https://svn.codehaus.org/grails/branches/GRAILS_1_1/src/groovy/grails/test/GrailsUnitTestCase.groovy) Just add 'Map savedMetaClasses = [:]' to your test case and then copy the registerMetaClass and tearDown methods. This enables you to use the above method in integration tests. Thanks.